# How to Set Default Yaml For R Markdown Documents?

Tags: pdf, yaml, latex, r-markdown

This is what I typically put at the top of my documents in R markdown:

```yaml
---
title: Title
author: Amar Al-Zubaidi
date: \today
mainfont: Inconsolata Nerd Font
sansfont: Inconsolata Nerd Font
monofont: Inconsolata Nerd Font
fontsize: 11pt
table-use-row-colors: true
bibliography: /home/amarakon/Documents/bibliography.bib
csl: /home/amarakon/Documents/Citations/apa-no-initials.csl
classoption: letterpaper
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
    template: eisvogel
    number_sections: true
---
```

I do pretty much the same thing for every document.
In fact, the only thing I change for every document is the title.
I want to know how I can put all of these values in a file (except for the title), and change my compile command to read that file when compiling. This is the command I use to compile:

```sh
R -e "rmarkdown::render('file.Rmd')"
```

My end goal is to only have to put something like this in my Rmarkdown document:

```yaml
---
title: my-title
---
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question not that long ago using [this information](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/document-templates.html).

Since I had worked on that question, I only had to clone my last template and update the skeleton to create your template.

You won't have a YAML with just your title. However, all of the elements that you specified you wanted would be pre-written in the RMD file when you open a new file using this template.

You can see this repository at [fraupflaume/customYAML2](https://github.com/fraupflaume/customYAML2).

To install this template (it's not a package per se; there's no library):

```
devtools::install_github("fraupflaume/customYAML2")
```

When you want to start a new RMD script, go to templates -> Custom YAML -> customYAML2.

[image]

If you wanted to change this down the road, you can fork or clone that repository and edit it to your heart's content.

[image]

BTW:: let me know if you want me to remove the images. (It has your name in them: here and on Github.)

Comment: Thank you so much! But I use VIM to edit my .Rmd files and not Rstudio. How can I specify the custom YAML template without Rstudio? Also, is having a git repository mandatory? Because I want to change the settings a bit and have multiple templates. I want to do it locally on my computer without a git repository.

Comment: No, Git is not necessary. The very first hyperlink I provided will bring you to a package that is designed around making templates. I have used VIM as an interface, so I don't know if that will work, though. It may give you ideas that will work, if that, in and of itself doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. How do I specify the template without using Rstudio?

Comment: Also, If I do not install the template using git, in which directory do I place the files?